# Background service using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a scenario where a background service has to periodically call the rest service. The condition where the service has to run or not is determined through a state stored in a context. I was wondering what the best way would be to create/instantiate this background service. Given that the service uses hooks, it needs to be in component.

Given the following simplified structure, I would like the service to be added into the MyContext element. However, given that the service component does not return anything, react gives me the following error "JSX element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements" - which makes sense to me.

```
<app>
 <MyContext>
  <MyBackgroundService />
  <MyUi />
 </MyContext>
</app>
```

I don't want to wrap all child components into MyBackgroundService element. Ideally, the code should run as it is. A possible solution is to return just an empty `React.Fragement` element, however, it feels more like a dirty workaround.

What would be the ideal solution to that? Am I completely on a wrong path and should I manage the instantiation of the background service in a different way? If so, how do I access the context?

Comment: Does the "background service" do anything other then just running in the background? Does it update some state, depends on some state, or anything?

Comment: @goto1 it just needs to read the state from MyContext, but it does not write back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just creating a custom hook that does the "background service" stuff that you need:

```js
function useBackgroundService(someStateFromContext) {
  const [backgroundService, setBackgroundService] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const bgService = setInterval(() => {
      // check the condition for running the background service
      // for example, to skip the API call, or whatever
      if (someStateFromContext !== 0) {
        return
      }
      callAPI()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(
            `ran bg service with value from context: ${someStateFromContext}`
          )
        })   
    }, 2000)

    setBackgroundService(bgService)

    // make sure you clean up when you no longer need it,
    // for example when component unmounts
    function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(bgService)
    }

    return cleanup;

    // since this `hook` relies on some value from context
    // make sure you include this in your dependency array
    // so that a new background service can be created,
    // and old one be destroyed, when state from context changes
  }, [someStateFromContext])

  // optionally, return `backgroundService`
  return backgroundService;
}
```

Then, in your `App` component, or whatever, just simply use this `hook`:

```js
// sample context
const MyContext = React.createContext({
  count: 0
})

function App() {
  const myContext = useContext(MyContext)

  useBackgroundService(myContext.count)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's a link to an example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-hodgkin-65861?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [build a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and call it within `App` (`<app>`) component.

Currently, you have a component which uses hooks without rendering a thing:

```js
const MyBackgroundService () => {
  // useHooks

  // No return causes "JSX element type 'void' ..."

  // With return without any functionality is useless.
  // Memory waste, and loses the functionality of custom hooks
  // like returning a value.
  // return <></>
}
```

Comment: I use the useContext() hook to read data from the "MyContext". If I call it from the <app>, the context will not be available at this stage yet, right? So it's not feasible solution.

Comment: It does, you supply to `MyContext` some initial state which is available in <app>, it must be in the same scope.